# Nifi: how to get flowfile based on filefilter

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to get  flowfiles which have filter like  this `session.get(fileSize>1)`
but  this example  doesn't  work  for  me  what  should  i change to make  this  task  work?(p.s  can  you  give me any  better  explanation about  getting sessions  by filter)

Answer (score 0):

That version of session.get() takes a FlowFileFilter object. In your code above you are passing a boolean (if fileSize is even defined at that point). The good news is that since the FlowFileFilter interface has a single method, you can use closure coercion to provide a closure as a FlowFileFilter object. This is an example of a Groovy script accepting only flow files whose size > 1:

```
import static org.apache.nifi.processor.FlowFileFilter.FlowFileFilterResult

def flowFiles = session.get({f -> 
   return f.size > 0 ? FlowFileFilterResult.ACCEPT_AND_CONTINUE 
          : FlowFileFilterResult.REJECT_AND_CONTINUE}
 as FlowFileFilter)

flowFiles?.each {session.transfer(it, REL_SUCCESS)}
```